# Spring @Retryable - reference thrown exception in delayExpression

Tags: spring-retry

I have a service that calls a 3rd party rate-limited API.  The API follows the common pattern of returning a `429` response code w/ a `Retry-After` header containing the amount of time to wait before making another API call when the allowed rate has been exceeded.

I want to use spring-retry's `@Retryable` annotation with `delayExpression` to dynamically set the delay for each retry based on the `Retry-After` value returned from the API.  I reviewed the [spring-retry documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/main/README.md) but could not figure out how (or if it is even possible) to reference the thrown exception in the `delayExpression`.

It seems you can reference the thrown exception as `#root` in the `@Retryable.exceptionExpression`, but in `@Backoff.delayExpression` I can only access the method arguments on the `#root` object - I can't figure out how to reference the thrown exception.

Is what I am trying to do possible? I know about `RetryTemplate` but would like to keep this simple w/ `@Retryable` if I can!

```java
@Component
public class MyService {

    @Retryable(retryFor = {RateLimitExceededException.class},
            backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#root.retryAfter")) // I want the value from thrownException.retryAfter
    public void doSomeApiCall(String parameters) {
        // do some API call, get a 429 response
        long retryAfter = 30000; // dynamic, parsed from API response's Retry-After header
        throw new RateLimitExceededException(retryAfter);
    }

    public static class RateLimitExceededException extends RuntimeException {
        protected long retryAfter;
        public RateLimitExceededException(long retryAfter) {
            this.retryAfter = retryAfter;
        }
        public long getRetryAfter() { return this.retryAfter; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; currently, only the method arguments are available for evaluating the expression at runtime.

Feel free to open a new feature request issue on GitHub.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues

You can, however, use `@Retryable` with a custom interceptor (using a `RetryTemplate`) so the business code can remain simple.

```java
    /**
     * Retry interceptor bean name to be applied for retryable method. Is mutually
     * exclusive with other attributes.
     * @return the retry interceptor bean name
     */
    String interceptor() default "";
```